# Need help troubleshooting TPCIP.sys BSOD

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, drivers, bsod

I had a couple of BSOD on win 7 x64, I ran the software WhoCrashed on the minidumps and it shows something like this:

```
Your computer crashed
crash dump file: C:\Windows\Minidump\032814-19921-01.dmp
This was probably caused by the following module: tcpip.sys (tcpip+0x1A7C88) 
Bugcheck code: 0x1E (0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
Error: KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED
file path: C:\Windows\system32\drivers\tcpip.sys
product: Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
company: Microsoft Corporation
description: TCP/IP Driver
Bug check description: This indicates that a kernel-mode program generated an exception which the error handler did not catch.
This appears to be a typical software driver bug and is not likely to be caused by a hardware problem. 
The crash took place in a standard Microsoft module. Your system configuration may be incorrect. Possibly this problem is caused by another driver on your system that cannot be identified at this time.
```

I am using [this wifi adapter (UGL2454-U2ZA)](http://www.eusso.com/Models/Wireless/UGL2454-U2ZA/UGL2454-U2ZA.htm), which I think it's causing the problem since it only happened when it's connected. Once crashed when I accidentally disconnected it from the usb and connected it back, other time while playing an online game, most of the times everything works fine tho.

First thing I though was I was using the 32b version of the driver, but no, I am using the 64b version I got from http://www.eusso.com/download/download_driver.htm I had to download the Win Vista version since they don't provide one for W7.

If I run ncpa.cpl and see the Wireless Network Connection, windows says its an "Atheros AR5007UG", I tried findind a W7 driver for that but couldn't find it either.

I am not sure what to do next, what should I do to continue troubleshooting this issue?

Comment: `I had to download the Win Vista version since they don't provide one for W7`. Do you want to fix it right and fix it for good? If so, acquire an adapter that's supported on Windows 7.

Comment: I think that there are probably a zillion USB wireless adapters available for Windows 7 and if it was me I would purchase one of those.

Comment: Well I live in a really poor country and the price of an USB wireless adapter can feed a family for weeks, I wouldnt be asking for help if I could buy a new one buddy.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same problem with Atheros AR5007UG USB wireless.
Here the solution:

1. Install latest drivers for Win7 64-bit http://www.digicom.it/comuni/driver/USBWave54/UsbWav54_Win.zip
2. Disable TCP/IPv6 protocol in device properties.
3. Disable WinpkFilter
4. Configure the device setting:

   - 802.11b Preamble --> LONG ONLY
   - Scan Valid Interval --> 120

enjoy